# if statement not executed in for loop android

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

I've got a very weird issue. I've got this Procedure object that contains two rules. Now I wanted to loop out those rules with a for loop and get 1 rule back. But I always get null. It looks like he is skipping the if statement and directly goes to my return null part.

The name of the first rule is age, and the name of the other rule is accidents. I've included the method here.

My log is giving back:

> rulename: 'age' and variable: 'accidents' and is true ?: 'false'
>
> rulename: 'accidents' and variable: 'accidents' and is true ?: 'true'

```
private Rule searchRule(String ruleName)
    {
        List<Rule> test = this.procedureObject.getRules();

        for(Rule rule : test)
        {
            Log.d("debug", "rulename: '" + rule.getName() + "' and variable: '"+ruleName+"' and is true ?: '"+rule.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ruleName)+"'");
            if(rule.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ruleName))
            {
                return rule;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**EDIT: it works now.**

I just changed this in the calling code:

```
Rule makeRule = RuleFactory.getNewRuleClassNameInstance(this.searchRule(ref2.getName()).getClass().getSimpleName());
```

to:

```
Rule foundRule = this.searchRule(ref2.getName());

Rule makeRule = RuleFactory.getNewRuleClassNameInstance(foundRule.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

And then it suddenly works.

Comment: It sure looks like the conditional block should be executed. So we can be 100% sure which is running maybe throw a log statement just before each `return` (have you stepped through in a debugger?).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Your code.just debug your code properly so you can check your Log statement execution. Or May be out of sync..!

Comment: @MichaelBurr yes I stepped step by step through the debugger. It's really weird behavior..

Comment: @user370305 I checked it with my debugger it is in sync.

Comment: @user370305 just tried that.. that doesn't work either.

Comment: Please show the calling code, and add logging *inside* the `if` statement.

Comment: @imran khan: why? return rule; should get out of the method... no break necessary...

Comment: @JonSkeet It keeps getting weirder.. He goes in to the IF, gives me the log but doesn't return anything. And goes to the return null part.

Comment: Why do you say that the function always return null? May be the problem is where you are making the call to this function and not in the function. Plz add the calling code and add a log statement above each return statement so we can be sure which statement is actually getting executed.

Comment: @VinceV.: It sounds like your calling code may be wrong, giving you odd diagnostics.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've added some screenshots with debugger info. the calling code: this.searchRule(ref2.getName()); Where I'm sure ref2.getName() is accidents.

Comment: @VinceV.: That doesn't show how you're using the result in the calling code though. I believe that the method is being called - but I can also easily believe that you're using the result incorrectly.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've added a screenshot with my calling code.

Comment: Can you break your calling code in two steps such that this.searchRule(ref2.getName()) is separate? Just to make sure that the problem is with this function and not rest of your code.

Comment: @VinceV.: Please stop posting screenshots - post actual code, which is a lot clearer to read. For diagnostic purposes, it would be a lot clearer if you'd just assign the result to a local variable, and then log that. Instead you've got an enormous long line, calling 5 methods in the same statement. The problem could easily be in `getNewRuleClassNameInstance`.

Comment: @binW When I do that, the function works properly.. Which is weird, because I was debugging in the method itself and in that method it failed.

Comment: @JonSkeet I broke my code up in pieces like you implied and now it functions properly. But isn't it weird ? Because in my method itself the if statement wasn't evaluated..

Comment: Glad to know the function works correctly. So does that mean your program no longer has error or the error was somewhere else like getNevRuleClassNameInstance?

Comment: @binW Well I didn't change anything just broke up my code. I'm updating my post right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed:

```
Rule makeRule = RuleFactory.getNewRuleClassNameInstance(this.searchRule(ref2.getName()).getClass().getSimpleName());
```

to:

```
Rule foundRule = this.searchRule(ref2.getName());
Rule makeRule = RuleFactory.getNewRuleClassNameInstance(foundRule.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

and then it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
if(rule.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ruleName))
{
  Log.d("debug", "rulename: '" + rule.getName() + "' and variable: '"+ruleName+"' and is true ?: '"+rule.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ruleName)+"'");
  return rule;
}
```